# KineticJS easing

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I created a shape in KineticJS and I animate it with tween.

```
    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
         node: rect, 
         duration: 1,
         easing: Kinetic.Easings.BackEaseOut,
         y: 100
    });
```

During reverse is it possible to change the easing?

Currently I have do that : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMWWh/1/)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work... But this is not really core func...

```
stage.on('mouseover', function() {
    tween.tween.func = Kinetic.Easings.BounceEaseOut;
    tween.play();
});

stage.on('mouseout', function() {
    tween.tween.func = Kinetic.Easings.BounceEaseIn;
    tween.reverse();
});
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I want with one exception. When the cursor is on the shape and you immediately withdrew, the reverse does not use easing. A solution to fix this?

Comment: Then, the better is maybe to use two tweens (instantiate each time), cause I think if the first tween isn't finished when the second occurs, the begin point will be wrong. Other way is to make to be sure that the first tween is finish (using onFinish property) before fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your **Custom easing function** with

[Easing Functions Generator](http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm) by [Robert Penner](http://robertpenner.com/easing/)

and use it instead of default easing presets:

```
// generated example 
var customEasingFunction = function(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts=(t/=d)*t;
    var tc=ts*t;
    return b+c*(63.2425*tc*ts + -185.23*ts*ts + 198.58*tc + -93.89*ts + 18.2975*t);
};

var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
     node: rect, 
     duration: 1,
     easing: customEasingFunction, // use it insead of default preset
     y: 100
});
```